# Cannot find error symbol in Android Studio

Tags: android

```
 String sAux=getResources().getString(R.string.ShareText);
sAux+="\n\n";
sAux+="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";
sAux+=getPackageName();
sAux+="\n\n"; 

// or
String sAux=getResources().getString(R.string.ShareText);
sAux=sAux+"\n\n"+"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+getPackageName()+"\n\n";
```

I got an error in these codes.
I Solved This Problem This Way.

```
 String sAux=getResources().getString(R.string.ShareText);
String s1="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";
String s2="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";
String s= String.format("%s\n\n %s %s \n\n",sAux, s1,s2);
```

I Didn't Know If It Was A Suitable Solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think "%s" are expecting additional string arguments, but you have only provided "sAux", "s1", and "s2". You should remove the extra "%s from the format string. Here's the code:

```
String sAux = getResources().getString(R.string.ShareText);
String s1 = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";
String s2 = "your_app_package_name";  // Replace with your actual package name
String s = String.format("%s\n\n %s%s \n\n", sAux, s1, s2);
```

This should resolve the issue with the "String.format" function.
I think above code will help you.

Comment: Thank you. Does it make sense to use it this way? Is there another solution?